# Can't exit Emacs with error "End of file during parsing"

Tags: debugging, error-handling

Every time I press c-x c-c to exit Emacs, it shows "End of file during parsing" in the minibuffer.  I cursorily examined my .emacs and did not find any mismatching parenthesis. Any idea what's the best route to fix this?

*Edit*: I confirmed that .emacs does not have mismatching parentheses with check-parens.

*Edit 2*: About `kill-emacs-hook`, I found it is related to keyfreq.  After commenting out the following from .emacs, the issue is resolved.  But I don't understand why it suddenly stops working:

```
;; keyfreq
;; https://github.com/dacap/keyfreq

;(require 'keyfreq)
;(keyfreq-mode 1)
;(keyfreq-autosave-mode 1)
```

Comment: If you know or suspect which file is at issue (e.g., something you recently edited), then open it up in Emacs and type `M-x check-parens`.  You may find the culprit such as a missing parentheses or a missing double quote.  Fix the error, `M-x eval-buffer` and see if that fixes your issue.  It think you are going to love `check-parens`!

Comment: See if `emacs-kill-hook` is set to something you'd not expect to be there (reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Killing-Emacs.html ). If you just need to exit Emacs, set this variable to nil via `M-: (setq emacs-kill-hook nil)`.

Comment: @lawlist check-parens did not reveal anything wrong to fix in .emacs.  I don't recall editing any Emacs configuration.

Comment: @wvxvw describe variable for `emacs-kill-hook` says no match?

Comment: Check what you use on `kill-emacs-hook` and `kill-emacs-query-functions`.  Those are invoked when you quit Emacs. Find out where you are fiddling with them in your init file (or in code that it loads). (You can use `emacs -Q` to run Emacs without your init file.)

Comment: @wvxvw: It's `kill-emacs-hook`, not `emacs-kill-hook`. ;-)

Comment: Learn the source code of keyfreq yourself, it may do something like `(read "(")`, which will throw the error you described, since the problem is related to keyfreq and you are interested.

Comment: @Drew yeah, I was too sleepy when I wrote that, but I left the reference!

Comment: Try to run `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, try again, and paste the resulting backtrace into your question.  I presume that keyfreq somehow fails to load its database.

Comment: @MengLu Looks like the `keyfreq` package is storing the key frequencies in an alist which is saved in a file. Did you manually modify that file? Either way, try removing that file and uncommenting the `keyfreq` setup and see if the issue repeats. Also as @lunaryorn said, the backtrace will be very helpful.

Comment: You can answer your own question, please put answers in the answers.